# How to store HTTPErrorResponse objects from multiple HTTP requests in an array?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to build an API validator in my Angular application. I have a list of URLs that I need to GET or POST, and store any HTTP errors in an array which will then be displayed in the UI.

I have implemented the following service to do this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataSource, ConfigValidationErrorObject } from './customTypes';

@Injectable()
export class ApiValidationService {
  apiValidationErrors: Array<ConfigValidationErrorObject> = new Array<ConfigValidationErrorObject>();

  constructor(
    private _httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  validate(dataSourceArray: Array<DataSource>): Array<ConfigValidationErrorObject> {
    dataSourceArray.map((url) => { this.validateApi(dataSource) });

    return this.apiValidationErrors;
  }

  validateApi(dataSource: DataSource) {
    if (dataSource.httpRequestType === 'GET') {
      this.executeGetRequest(dataSource.url, dataSource.options).subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data),
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.addApiValidationError(error);
        }
      );
    }

    if (dataSource.httpRequestType === 'POST') {
      this.executePostRequest(dataSource.url, dataSource.body, dataSource.options).subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data),
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.addApiValidationError(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }

  executeGetRequest(url: string, options: any) {
    return this._httpClient.get(url);
  }

  executePostRequest(url: string, body: any, options: any) {
    return this._httpClient.post(url, body, options);
  }

  addApiValidationError(httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) {
    const apiValidationError: ConfigValidationErrorObject = {
      message: httpErrorResponse.message,
    };

    this.apiValidationErrors.push(apiValidationError);
  }
}
```

When I use the `validate()` method in my component, I want the array it returns to be populated with my custom error objects. But I get an empty array back, even when errors are being thrown (they are being logged to the console correctly). I expect it's because of asynchronous HTTP requests.

I'm reading up on Observables, but I'm not sure if I can use them because I need the error objects and not the data returned from the HTTP requests. **I want to know if I need to use Observables or if I should be looking at Promises? If I need to use Observables, could anyone please help me get started with it for my problem.**

I'm pretty new to Angular, so I'm having trouble deciding how to solve this issue. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go like this

```
forkJoin(
  getCallOne()
    .pipe(map(() => null), catchError(error => {/* what you want to do here */})),
  getCallTwo()
    .pipe(map(() => null), catchError(error => {/* what you want to do here */})),
  postCallOne()
    .pipe(map(() => null), catchError(error => {/* what you want to do here */})),
  PostCallTwo()
    .pipe(map(() => null), catchError(error => {/* what you want to do here */})),
).pipe(
  map(errors => errors.filter(error => !!error))
)
```

You can then either **subscribe** to it, or use the **async** pipe in your template

- **forkJoin** creates an array of observables and emits only when all calls are completed
- map the answers to **null** because you won't use it (apparently)
- use **catchError** to catch the error and return it as a valid observable
- **map** the final errors to filter only the errors (removing the **null** values of valid calls)